# Is it possible to install an Objective-C AND Swift framework using CocoaPods?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, alamofire, pinterest

I want to install the Pinterest SDK (Obj-C) and Alamofire (Swift).  Per CocoaPods (https://blog.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-0.36/) you can make CocoaPods integrate to your project via frameworks instead of static libraries by specifying `use_frameworks!`...which I think prevents the Pinterest SDK from working since it's static (or at least that's what I believe since I tried to install Alamofire after having Pinterest SDK installed and it would no longer recognize Pinterest.

Is there a way around this?  Or do I need to pick one to install via CocoaPods and install the other via dragging and dropping?